# Laravel How can i set my route for this case?

Tags: laravel, routes

Thoses are my functions in InfoControllers. They will be applied in the view : `Show.blade.php` and the url to `Show.blade.php` is `/cvs/{id}`.

My problem:  wow can I set my route for `infoController` to the view shows and for the same url ?

[image: InfoController]

Comment: Bonjour Yassine, please do not post code as images (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).   You should edit the question, remove the image and paste your code directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

to set routes in laravel open `web.php` file inside `routes` folder. and add this line to it :

```
Route::get('/cvs/{id}', 'InfosController@index');
```

this will make laravel to run index method inside InfosController when the "/cvs/{id}" url is requested.
but you need to get the {id} from the url, right? just add `$id` argument to your index method :

```
public function index($id) {
    ...
}
```

more about laravel routes :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing